# Power BI Custom visual for HeatMap

Tags: powerbi, heatmap, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am using a HeatMap custom visual from "https://github.com/sjkp/heatmap/releases" and trying to change the radius of heatmap based on a measure, for example

Name    Duration

A       20

B       200

C       60

D       90

E       100

The heatmap should show a circle with most radius or some differentiation at visual level for B followed by E, D, C and A.

Is this possible or has anyone tried it?